# AdMob loadAd java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

After upgrading from Google Play Services 11.8.0 to 12.0.1 the following errors started appearing:

```
Exception java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class o.a because it failed compile-time verification (declaration of 'o.a' appears in /data/app/com.me.myapp-1/base.apk)
com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzac.zza (zzac.java)
com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzd.zza (zzd.java)
com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzd.zza (zzd.java)
com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zza.zzb (zza.java)
com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzx.zzb (zzx.java)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmw.getAdSize (zzmw.java)
com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.loadAd (BaseAdView.java)
com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd (AdView.java)
sp.app.myWorkClock.MyActivity.onCreate (PunchClockActivity.java)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6221)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1119)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2614)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2726)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:172)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1421)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:145)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5835)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1399)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

No other relevant change in the app. 
At the moment we're trying to simply ignore the exception:

```
try {
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
} catch (VerifyError e) {
}
```

Anyone got better solution?

Comment: Have you tried updating to 15.0.0?